# Windows 7 to Linux: install without CD/DVD or USB drive

Tags: linux, windows, system-installation

Update Sorry, Question has multiple parts see below for details:
I have been using Windows for many years and only used Linux from the command line, but want to shift after realizing Windows is sloowww.

Following http://mightydreams.blogspot.in/2007/09/i-am-describing-here-method-to-install.html and http://www.instantfundas.com/2007/08/install-any-linux-distro-directly-from.html

Is there a better set of instructions? (I do not have a USB or CD/DVD)

Have got  "debian-7.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso" and disks 2 & 3 and renamed 1 to `d1.iso`. Step 2 says to copy `vmlinuz` and `initrd.gz` to the \C drive

But I found these files in 3 places (I did a `7z.exe l -path-to-iso- >files.list`)

```
install.amd\gtk\vmlinuz
install.amd\vmlinuz (update plan on using this but stuck at grub see below)
install.amd\xen\vmlinuz
```

And similarly:

```
install.amd\initrd.gz 
install.amd\xen\initrd.gz
install.amd\gtk\initrd.gz
```

Which one to use?

---

Stuck at grub ...

Made the entry using bcdedit but it says grub is not valid. downloaded grub from the sourceforge site, copied it and pointed to it

```
bcdedit /create /d Linux /application  OSLOADER
bcdedit /set  {c1e718e7-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29} device partition=c: 
bcdedit /set   {c1e718e7-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29}  path \grub\grub.exe

bcdedit -v
```

Gives me

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {c1e718e2-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29}
resumeobject            {c1e718e1-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29}
displayorder            {c1e718e2-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29}
            {c1e718e7-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {c1e718e2-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {c1e718e3-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {c1e718e1-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29}
nx                      OptIn

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {c1e718e7-3d90-11e1-a4c8-b5a356ae5e29}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \grub\grub.exe
description             Linux
```

Comment: Can you use a USB pendrive instead?

Comment: embarrassed to say not this month. lost the two drives i had and don't have the budget to buy more. is it very hard from the drive?

Comment: Haven't done so in a while but it should be possible and not that hard. Its just easier from a USB drive is all. And no reason for embarrassment, happens to the best of us :)

Comment: You don't want the `xen`, I am not sure why you would have a `gtk` vmlinuz though. I'm not sure, but I would just use the "normal" one, the one that is in `install.amd/` not the ones from the subdirectories.

Comment: stuck at grub, see edit to question ... if can help will be glad :)

Comment: can use with win-loader but now my internet connection is the issue - it needs a login. I have debian downloaded (ISO, extracted the 3 dvd isos too), can get the installation GUI to start after i reboot, but not able to point the intaller to my local drive to find the release files tried '    file:///d/d2/ it is on my c drive and if i launch the terminal i can see them. now to use them ! @terdon

Comment: Not sure what you mean here but this is straying from the original question. It might be better to post a new question with the details of this problem.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78789/windows-7-to-debian-linux-install-without-cd-dvd-or-usb-drive-or-net-during-ins

Comment: @terdon fyi finally got debian. got a USB, used the cd iso as the dvd ones are too big for fat32 and windows - i do not know to make 2 partitions in same usb. anyway its working finally!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian is my personal favorite distribution. However, I have been using Linux for more than a decade and know my way around it. It is not the best distro to start with. Since you are new to Linux, I would recommend [LinuxMint](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php) instead. It is based on Ubuntu which is based on Debian. It is easier to use without losing any of Debian's power or stability.

If you really really want to stick to a pure Debian, go for [Linux Mint Debian](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php), which is based directly on Debian, not Ubuntu and *is* a Debian in all ways. Everything you've read about Debian applies to LMDE as well. It just is slightly easier to install and configure, still not a beginner distro though.

Now, that said, the easiest way to install Debian from Windows is [win32-loader](http://goodbye-microsoft.com/):

```
== What is Win32-Loader? ==

win32-loader is a component of the Debian-Installer that runs on Windows and
has the ability to load the actual installer either from the network or from
CD-ROM media (as in the version included in the official CD images).

This executable is the standalone flavour, which downloads the Debian
Installer from official Debian mirrors.

== How does it work? ==

After the language choice, the executable prompts the user for some
options and tries to get defaults from the Windows environment. It then
downloads the Debian installer and kernel from official Debian mirrors. It
puts them in a Windows directory and safely modifies the Windows bootloader to
enable a choice between the legacy Windows installation and the Debian
installer at boot time.

On the next reboot, the user can choose to continue the installation of
Debian. The installation will be run using the defaults gathered from the
runtime analysis and user prompting.

== Installation Guide ==

As the Debian Installer is a minimal system, one might want to take a look at
the Debian Installation Guide before launching win32-loader.exe:

    http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/installmanual
```

---

You may also be interested in reading the Debian installation guide. Specifically sections [4.4. Preparing Files for Hard Disk Booting](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch04s04.html.en) and [Chapter 5. Booting the Installation System](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch05.html.en).

Comment: trying to decide between linux, kFreeBSD & hurd and  gnone & xfce. went with kFreeBSD with xfce. do you have a preference you would like to share?

Comment: @tgkprog only that you should learn to walk before you try to run. kFreeBSD is a "release in progress" and "a technology preview" it _really_ is not a good start to learn Linux. In fact, it's not even Linux, it uses the FreeBSD kernel. Why don't you first try a normal Debian install, learn your way around it and then go to experimental stuff?

Comment: okay thanks. i was just going to reboot! will redo it with linux + xfce ? or do u think the gnome for first try?

Comment: @tgkprog when it comes to higher level stuff like the Desktop Environment, go for whichever you want. The most user friendly and polished are gnome and kde, personally I really like Cinnamon. Xfce is fast and powerful but lacks certain features. All of them (and many others I haven't mentioned) are good and it is really just a personal choice.

Comment: accepted this as looks like it would have worked with a net connection during install

Comment: getting LMDE. could not get APT to work. am sure it was something simple but do not have enough patience to look around.

Comment: @tgkprog you could not get _apt_ to work? That is very strange. Just post your error message as a question and I'm sure we can figure it out.

Comment: it worked tried again today. this post is from my debian after working on eclpse :)  had to renmove the cd entries. as had installed from usb. http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=105437 Details here

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu can be installed like a regular program in windows to create a dual boot.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Comment: Reading about the different distros debian came out shining. Will keep this as my last ditch

Comment: That works pretty slow however. [You can turn it into a native one later however.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/635/how-to-convert-wubi-install-into-regular-install)

Comment: i guess i will try that tommoroow as the whole point was to get a faster os as i just need open office, eclipse, XAMPP, Jboss and other non windows apps anyway

Answer (score 1):

in fact you can burn your ISO file using USB device by using this http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
or if you are using linux system you can also use "dd" command.

Comment: but i'm not using linux nor have a usb

Comment: this finally helped. did get usb finally

Comment: +1 thanks, this worked. and now using same for ubunutu on another.