# Windows 7 to Debian Linux: install without CD/DVD or USB drive or net during install

Tags: linux, system-installation, grub2, grub-legacy

Installed : Windows 7 home premium. Now want Debian Linux.

Tried a couple of things (see question below). Got installer menu using  win32-loader.exe of Debian from the goodbye-ms site.

But I have a fibre optic internet that  needs a login so when the installer came up, I could set keyboard, timezone, detect network automatically ... but stuck when it wants to get packages.

Using bit torrent I have the 3 Debian DVD iso files debian-7.0.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso ... at  /d/ (in my Windows c:) renamed them to d1.iso, d2.iso ...

I also have them extracted at /d/d2/ (in my Windows c:)

/win32-loader/ is the folder made by win32-loader.exe

It has base URL to http://cdn.debian.net/debian/dists/stable/ is there a way to change this to /d/d2 where I extracted everything (I can download more files and put them there if needed).

Or can I edit the grub setting so it loads from local?

This was my trial 2 edited C:\win32-loader\grub.cfg Tried loopback but  guess  did not do it right as I just get a grub prompt.

```
loopback loop /d/d2
linux (loop) /boot/vmlinuz
initrd /boot/initrd.gz
```

Note: I know I can get Ubuntu installer as suggested and upvoted on [Windows 7 to Linux: install without CD/DVD or USB drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78620/) but I would like to get Debian and dual boot to Windows or separately to Debian.

How do I find out if its grub or grub 2?

I also tried to put grub interdependently using winGrub but need better instructions for that for Windows 7 as it did not work (edited Windows using bcdedit but when I try to boot using that get an error), results of that too are on first question.

Comment: finally got it to work with a usb with cd iso that can fit on fat32 (each file is not more than limit). still do not know if can do it with a hdd only om windows vista

Comment: this is grub legacy? http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/33966